# Jenkins: use ssh-agent and git plugins together

Tags: ubuntu, git, jenkins, github, ssh-agent

So, I have the following situation: a server with dedicated users for each project (e.g. `foo`) and a jenkins server which runs as a `jenkins` user.
I've generated an SSH key pair for my `foo` user and added the public one as a deploy key to a github repo. (I verified I can clone the repo with the `foo` user)

In Jenkins I setup authentication in "Manage Jenkins" > "Manage Credentials" as a "SSH username with private key" with Username "foo" and `foo`'s private key in a "Global" scope.

So I configured my Jenkins job with the *correct workspace* (e.g. `/home/foo/deployment` with full ownership for user `foo` obviously) and *using the credentials "foo"*. For "Source code management" I wanted to use the SSH URL of my repo (e.g. git@github.com:foo/foo.git)
However it immediately notifies me there's a permission problem:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@github.com:foo/foo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I use the https version of the URL (https://github.com/foo/foo.git) the error disappears, but when I run the job I get the following errors in the console output:

```
Started by user developer
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /home/foo/deployment
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/foo/foo.git
 > git init /home/foo/deployment # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/foo/deployment
    [long stacktrace]
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git init /home/foo/deployment" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: /home/foo/deployment/.git: Permission denied
    [long stacktrace]
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

The key pair doesn't use a passphrase, I'd like to add one though if I get this working first.
Jenkins runs on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64) box.

What am I missing here? It appears the credentials I provided aren't being used, which explains why it explodes on permissions. But I don't understand why they're not being used? And why can't use the `git@` URL?

Since it chokes on a permission problem with `git init` I ran that manually in `/home/foo/deployment`, but rerunning the Jenkins job it chokes on `git fetch`, again with permissions problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes, very silly me. The SSH user agent obviously only allows the `jenkins` user to connect to the remote repo as `foo`, but doesn't grant it permissions to write to the local file system...